# Cannot set property 'round' of undefined in ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am learning nodejs from "secrete of ninja" book.
I have an ejs program which I copied from book to run but it showing following error while I don't make any change in the program.

This is an error:

```
ejs.filters.round = function(number, decimalPlaces) {
               ^ 
 Cannot set property 'round' of undefined
```

I have this code:

```
 var ejs = require('ejs');
 var template = '<%=: price * 1.145 | round:2 %>';
 var context = {price: 21};


ejs.filters.round = function(number, decimalPlaces) {

number = isNaN(number) ? 0 : number;
decimalPlaces = !decimalPlaces ? 0 : decimalPlaces;

var multiple = Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces);
return Math.round(number * multiple) / multiple;
};

console.log(ejs.render(template, context));
```

can anybody suggest me where am I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly you are using version 2.

> Version 2 of EJS makes some breaking changes with this version
>   (notably, **removal of the filters feature**). [Source](https://github.com/tj/ejs)

---

**EDIT:**

You can either switch to a version before version2, or create your own object for filter, which then can be extended to contain your own defined filters

Comment: to run this code successfully should I use older version of ejs?

Comment: @gotchha. yes.. any version before v2

Comment: otherwise you can create your own object for filter and create a round method in it

Comment: can you tell me how to install older version. I serched in google but does not work. I have donloaded this one with  `sudo npm install ejs`

Comment: example `npm install <package>@<version>`

Comment: @NaeemShaikh how do I create my own object for filters? An example would be super helpful.

Comment: @amarprabhu.. there are several options, if you are using express, one way is to write a function like `app.locals.funName=function(){}`, this wil be accessible throughout your application, also in your view engine.